# Bigquery - How to nest columns to prevent unwanted aggregations in 1:many relationships?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

sales table:

| date | item_no | store_group | sales_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 123 | A | 1234 |
| 1/1/2022 | 123 | B | 7246 |
| 1/1/2022 | 123 | C | 6516 |

inventory table:

| date | item_no | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 123 | 10000 |

A typical join on date and item_no would result in the stock of 10,000 repeated in the 3 rows. How do I make it look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/679HJ.png) on BI tools like Data Studio?

Basically I want sales_qty to be shown at the 'date x item_no x store_group' level, while stock is kept at 'date x item_no' level.

Comment: Have a look at [array_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg) function of BigQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select * from (
  select date, item_no, array_agg(struct(store_group, sales_qty)) sales
  from sales group by date, item_no
) join inventory using (date, item_no)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you select date , item and stock in data studio you will see single line like of table inventory data. The moment you include, storeGroup or salesQty there will be multiple line like of table sale.

```
select s.date, s.item_no, s.store_group, sum(s.sales_qty) sales_qty, max(i.stock) stock
from sales s 
left join inventory i on s.date = i.date and s.item_no = i.item_no
group by s.date, s.item_no, s.store_group
```